# How to concatenate two tuples each shaped <class'tuple'>:(100,1) to one tuple shaped <class'tuple'>:(100,2) using python?

Tags: python, tuples, concatenation

I have two tuples called x1,x2 each shaped :(100,1).

The two tuples x1,x2 are both {ndarray} and have dtype of float64. The values of each are taken from a different normal distribution defined as follows:

x1= (0.5 +0.5*np.random.rand(100,1)) # random dist with mean 0.5 and std 0.5

x2 = (0 +0.5*np.random.rand(100,1)) # random dist with mean 0 and std 0.5

I want to concatenate the two tuples to form a new tuple called x3 to be shaped  :(100,2).

How can this be achieved using python?

Comment: please elaborate it more with example

Comment: Tuples don't have shapes. It sounds like you're getting things mixed up with NumPy or something like that.

Comment: x3 = np.column_stack([x1,x2]) works for me. Thanks @Georgy

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are generally immutable; as such, you can't append one to the other. However, you can create a new one from the two of them. Assuming you have `t1` and `t2`, try `tuple(zip(t1, t2))` and see if that meets your needs. You'll end up with each element of `t1` paired with the corresponding element of `t2`.

```
>>> t1 = tuple(f"a{n}" for n in range(100))
>>> t2 = tuple(f"b{n}" for n in range(100))
>>> t3 = tuple(zip(t1, t2))
>>> numpy.shape(t3)
(100, 2)
>>> t3[:3]
(('a0', 'b0'), ('a1', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2'))
```

---

After the comment and edits, it becomes clear that you're dealing with a numpy array, although it's not clear to me if the shape is `(100, 1)` or `(100,)` (e.g. 100 nested arrays of one element each or a single flat array of 100 elements). In either case, the reshaping can be handled with numpy functions:

```py
x = numpy.array([(n,) for n in range(100)])
y = numpy.array([(n,) for n in range(200, 300)])
combined = numpy.array([x.flatten(), y.flatten()])
finished = combined.transpose()
```

Note that the `.flatten()` calls won't be necessary if you don't have an array of tuples.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have edited the question and clarified that I am dealing with tuples of {ndarray} and dtype of float64.